# Script not found or unable to stat, one page and not others, same permissions

Tags: apache2

On a new installation of Ubuntu 14.04, I copied several php files, they worked fine in another computer.

The strange thing is almost all pages are showing right but with some of them I get 404 Not Found.

Error:

```
[Mon Aug 11 14:46:58.581444 2014] [:error] [pid 12123] [client 172.18.0.36:55110] script '/var/www/garantias/imprimir_solicitud.php' not found or unable to stat
```

From apache2.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: What are the permissions on the directory?

Comment: Thank you kraxor, I found my mistake, Now I have to use in the address the name of the file exactly as it is. Before I could use http://sistemas/garantias/imprimir_solicitud.php and it would show me the page, now I must use the name as it is: http//sistemas/garantias/Imprimir_solicitud.php. Notice the capital I in word "Imprimir"... that was all the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake, Now I have to use in the address the name of the file exactly as it is. Before I could use

```
sistemas/garantias/imprimir_solicitud.php
```

and it would show me the page, now I must use the name as it is:

```
http://sistemas/garantias/Imprimir_solicitud.php
```

Notice the capital I in word "Imprimir"... that was the problem.